# Meteor mongodb $inc with update

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I have this mongo collection and vars:

```
items:{
 type_one: 0,
 type_two: 0
}

var valueOne = 1;
var nameItem = type_one;
```

---

I try to update a value, but not work.
I tried this:

```
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, {$inc: { items.$.nameItem: valueOne}} );
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, {$inc: { "items.$.nameItem": valueOne}} );
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, {$inc: { "items."+nameItem: valueOne}} );
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, {$inc: { "items."+nameItem: 1}} );

var object = { $inc: { "items."+nameItem: valueOne} };
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, object );
var object = { $inc: { items.$.nameItem: valueOne} };
Collection.update({createdBy: user_id}, object );
```

But none works and I get this message:

```
"errorClass {error: 409, reason: "MinimongoError: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number", details: undefined, message: "MinimongoError: Cannot apply $inc modifier to non-number [409]", errorType: "Meteor.Error"}"
```

It's a issue o incompatibility?

Comment: can u show a sample document of your collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your query dynamically using the bracket `[]` operator. Also "nameItem" must be a string.

```js
var valueOne = 1;
var nameItem = 'type_one';
var inc = {};
inc[ 'items.' + nameItem ] = valueOne;
Collection.update({ createdBy: user_id }, { '$inc': inc } )
```

Answer (score 0):

The only possible reasons I can come up with this that either you inserted number into collection in the form of `String` or you're trying to increment with `String` value. Try using `parseInt(stringValue)` in your code.