# update array in mongoDB document by variable index

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb

How can I update an array in a mongoDB document by index, which is stored in a variable?

```
{
    _id: 'IDString',
    field: [ bla, bla, old, bla ];
}

let i = 2;
Collection.update(
    { _id: 'IDString' },
    { $set: 
        { 'field.$.i': 'new' }
    }
);
```

So the result should be:

```
{
    _id: 'IDString',
    field: [ bla, bla, new, bla ];
}
```

My code wouldn't work, as I want to use the *variable* `i`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Meteor mongodb $inc with update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33968094/meteor-mongodb-inc-with-update)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [**dot notation**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) syntax to set up your update document since this will access an element of an array by the zero-based index position. You would have to concatenate the array name with the dot (.) and zero-based index position, and enclose in quotes.

So in your example, you would need to set up the update document dynamically to produce

```
var update = { "$set": { "field.2": "new" } }
```

The following code snippet shows this:

```
var i = 2,
    update = { "$set": {} };

update["$set"]["field."+i] = "new";
db.collection.update({ "_id": "IDString" }, update)
```

Comment: Great solution! The same dictionary string approach helped me out
in pymongo as well. 
Here it is formatted for readability. I dislike dealing 
with variables and functions with the same name.

`var i = 2; 
var arr_update_dict = { "$set": {} }; 
arr_update_dict["$set"]["field."+i] = "new"; 

db.collection.update({ "_id": "IDString" }, arr_update_dict) `

Answer (score 0):

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: 'IDString', field.2 : 1 },
    { $set: {
        "field.$" : "new" }
    }
)
```

This should work, if not - comment below