# Mongo Document Increment Sequence is skipping numbers

Tags: mongodb, meteor, methods, sequence, auto-increment

I'm currently having issues when querying for one of my Documents inside a Database through Meteor.

Using this line of code I'm trying to retrieve the next sequence number out of the DB. But it sometimes skips numbers randomly for some reason.

```
var col = MyCounters.findOne(type);
MyCounters.update(col._id, {$inc: {seq: 1}});
return col.seq;
```

Not getting any kind of errors server side.
Does anybody know what the issue might be?

I'm on Meteor 1.4+

====================

Update

I also update another Collection with the new value obtained from `MyCounters` collection, so it would be something like this:

```
var col = MyCounters.findOne(type);
MyCounters.update(col._id, {$inc: {seq: 1}});
var barId = col.seq;

// declare barObject + onInsertError
barObject.barId = barId;
// ...
FooCollection.insert(barObject, onInsertError);
```

And FooCollection ends up having skipped sequence numbers up to 5000 sometimes.

Comment: Is this code running in a helper? I assume it's your intent to return the value of the sequence *before* the update?

Comment: In order to understand why this code is skipping numbers, you would have to describe how you are running it (e.g., in a loop, in a request handler, etc.). Particularly, it would be interesting if it is being called simultaneously, since it is not atomic and therefore subject to race conditions.

Comment: @FlorianWinter
The code is inside a Meteor Method which gets invoked before inserting into another to put the value as one of its attributes. 

I thought it could have been a race condition first, and added some logs and debugged it to see if there were any errors between invoking the sequence and inserting the document for the skipped numbers, but they were not.

Comment: @Rob This doesn't really help understanding your problem. In isolation, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted. The only potential problem is a race condition due to the separate findOne and update commands. If the code is executed simultaneously, both threads might run findOne first and get the same sequence number. It would be better to use findAndModify (https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/tutorial/create-an-auto-incrementing-field/)

This does not really answer your question, so I leave it as a comment, but it might actually solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks @FlorianWinter
Unfortunately Meteor does not support FindAndModify, and it would need to be "linked" through other Collection, since I get the counter from one Collection to insert it into a new Document into another. I will update my question to include this information as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you want increament at that item Document, you can use :

```
var col = MyCounters.findOne(type);
var valueOne = 1;
var nameItem = 'seq';
var inc = {};
inc[ nameItem ] = valueOne;
MyCounters.update({ _id: col._id }, { '$inc': inc } )
```

But if you want increament value from all Document from Collections MyCounters ( maks seq + 1 ) you can use :

```
var count = MyCounters.findOne({}, {sort:{seq:-1}}).seq;
count = count + 1;
MyCounters.update({_id:col._id}, {$set:{seq:count}})
```

I hope it work for you. Thanks

refer to : https://stackoverflow.com/a/33968766/4287229

Comment: Thanks Pamungkas but this doesn't really answer my question, I guess I'm already doing the first option you mentioned.
The issue is that it sometimes skips the increment number instead of 1 I can see it incremented 500 or more.